# no such column error in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying trying to insert values into my table, but am getting a no such column error. I was searching and saw that in most cases it was because they were missing quotation marks, but I seem to have them. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
CREATE TABLE students (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
first_name VARCHAR(255),
last_name VARCHAR(255),
grade INT,
passing BOOLEAN,
teacher_id INT,
FOREIGN KEY (teacher_id) REFERENCES teachers(id)
);

INSERT INTO students (first_name, last_name, grade, passing, teacher_id) 
VALUES (‘Ted’, ‘Mosby’, 84, true, 2);
```

> **Error: no such column: ‘Ted’**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `'` not `’` and `1` instead of `true`:

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers **0 (false) and 1 (true)**.

```
INSERT INTO students (first_name, last_name, grade, passing, teacher_id) 
VALUES ('Ted', 'Mosby', 84, 1, 2);
```

In case you want to use variables use same quotes:

```
INSERT INTO students (first_name, last_name, grade, passing, teacher_id) 
VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', 84, 1, 2);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7d12a/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦═════════════╦════════════╦════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ id  ║ first_name  ║ last_name  ║ grade  ║ passing  ║ teacher_id ║
╠═════╬═════════════╬════════════╬════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║  1  ║ Ted         ║ Mosby      ║    84  ║       1  ║          2 ║
╚═════╩═════════════╩════════════╩════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```